# How to position an element inside a css grid cell?

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

CSS Grid, three cells, three elements in each cell: header, paragraph, link. Each paragraph has different different length making the links not being aligned. Is there any way to align the links, preferably position  elements at the bottom of the cell?

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <h3>Item 1</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Item 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Item 3</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GYEobV

Answer (score 3):

You could mantain the `grid` layout for the outermost parent, turn your inner `div` into `flex` containers and finally self-aligning the link elements in the `flex-end` position:

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.grid div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: stretch;
}
.grid div a {
  margin-top: auto;
  width: 100%
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <h3>Item 1</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Item 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>Item 3</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using `position:absolute;` you can solve your problem check updated snippet

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.col {
  position: relative;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col">
    <h3>Item 1</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h3>Item 2</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h3>Item 3</h3>
    <p>Description</p>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like also this approach but maybe you should set some bottom padding, enough to avoid a possible overlap of the link over the paragraph (especially on links where the text occupies more than one line). Right now on chrome this doesn't happen thanks to default margin bottom applied to the paragraph.

Comment: yes  @fcalderan using this approach  need to set bottom margin or padding to the paragraph to avoid overlapping

Comment: I think this is the simplest one. I was messing with the absolute link positioning but I forgot to position parent div... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may have changed since the original answers were given, but currently the [well-supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=justify-items) [`justify-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items) and [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) properties are a convenient way to align items within grid cells, which is what the original question was asking.

For example, the following will align the contents of the grid cells to the bottom of the cells, as requested:

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```